# Handling onchange event in HTML.DropDownList Razor MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I'm handling an `onchange` event with a selected value by simple HTML like this:

```
<select onchange="location = this.value;">
         <option value="/product/categoryByPage?PageSize=15" selected="selected">15</option>
         <option value="/product/categoryByPage?PageSize=30" selected="selected">30</option>
         <option value="/product/categoryByPage?PageSize=50" selected="selected">50</option>
</select>
```

Doing it like this:

```
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
string[] itemArray = {"15","30","50"};

for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.Count(); i++)
{
    items.Add(new SelectListItem 
    { 
        Text = itemArray[i], 
        Value = "/product/categoryByPage?pageSize=" + itemArray[i]
    });
}

ViewBag.CategoryID = items;
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID")
```

How can I handle `onchange` with `@Html.DropDownList()`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

#### Description

You can use another overload of the `DropDownList` method. Pick the one you need and pass in 
a object with your html attributes.

#### Sample

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", null, new { @onchange="location = this.value;" })
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - SelectExtensions.DropDownList Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist.aspx)

Comment: How to use location?

Answer (score 6):

The way of dknaack does not work for me, I found this solution as well:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Chapters", ViewBag.Chapters as SelectList, 
                    "Select chapter", new { @onchange = "location = this.value;" })
```

where

```
@Html.DropDownList(controlName, ViewBag.property + cast, "Default value", @onchange event)
```

In the controller you can add:

```
DbModel db = new DbModel();    //entity model of Entity Framework

ViewBag.Chapters = new SelectList(db.T_Chapter, "Id", "Name");
```

Comment: @razor-code WHERE @ razor-code.  What does this even mean?  Where/why do I put two drop-down lists?