# How to get a DropDownList select action to trigger submit button in MVC 4?

Tags: drop-down-menu, web, submit, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a DropDownList in an MVC 4 web application that is used as a filter. When a new value is selected from the drop down, the user then has to click the submit button. Is there a way to get the DropDownList to perform the same submit action when a new item is selected from the drop down so I can eliminate the submit button altogether? No custom methods have been written for the submit button, I am just using the generic one that is in MVC.

Update: Code is as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("userName",Model.Users) <input type="submit" value="Search" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

p.s. first link in Google search results

Edit

```
@Html.DropDownList("userName",Model.Users new {onchange="this.form.submit()"})
```

Comment: this is quite a bit different than what I am dealing with. I have updated the question to contain my code.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973037/handling-onchange-event-in-html-dropdownlist-razor-mvc