# Fire event on change of value in dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a drop down in my page. on change of value in that drop down one event has to be fired.

**HTML/Razor**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Reason", new[] { new SelectListItem { Text="-Select-", Value= "-Select-",Selected=true }, new SelectListItem { Text="Price", Value= "Price" }, new SelectListItem { Text="3P", Value= "3P" }, new SelectListItem { Text="Freight Collect", Value= "Freight Collect" }, new SelectListItem { Text="Change in Relationships", Value= "Change in Relationships" }, }
```

I have tried the following code but the event is not getting fired.

Comment: $('#Reason').change(function () {
            alert($("#Reason").val());
            UpdateRecords();
        });

i am using following code

Comment: Can you show html/razor?

Comment: is the element #reason added dynamically ?i.e is it added after the jquery function is called??

Comment: check the console for any errors. Also encase your code inside `$(function() { // your code });`

Comment: @veena edit your question and put relevant code there, not in comments...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling onchange event in HTML.DropDownList Razor MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973037/handling-onchange-event-in-html-dropdownlist-razor-mvc)

Comment: @veena: Please post your code in your original post as it is better to read there, and please indent your code properly for readability purposes.

Comment: @veena: You also didn't show enough code of what is working. Please remember to give as much code and details of what you have tried and what did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the event handler when the document is ready, so you use `$(function () {});`:

```
$(function () {
    $("#Reason").on("change", function () { 
        // You're referring to the object itself, so you can use $(this).
        alert(this.value); 
        UpdateRecords(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: **+1** If you explain what and why.

Comment: it is not going inside the function itself

Comment: You are missing parenthensis here `$(this.val()` and `this.value` is enough for `select`

Comment: You can use `$(this).val();` or `this.value` <= this is cross browser so no need to use jQuery. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is once again a problem with `#Reason` not actually existing in the `DOM` when you try to attach the `event` Listener. You need to make sure the `DOM` is ready before you do this..

With either

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Code here..
});

$(function(){
   // Code here...
});
```

They are both the same

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your code to try and get your solution working. Below is what I came up with and it is tested. Please edit to fit in with your scenario.

I have indented your drop down markup for readability purposes:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Reason",
     new[]
     {
          new SelectListItem { Text="-Select-", Value= "-Select-", Selected = true },
          new SelectListItem { Text="Price", Value= "Price" },
          new SelectListItem { Text="3P", Value= "3P" },
          new SelectListItem { Text="Freight Collect", Value= "Freight Collect" },
          new SelectListItem { Text="Change in Relationships", Value= "Change in Relationships" }
     }
)
```

And the resulting output looks like this:

```
<select id="Reason" name="Reason">
     <option selected="selected" value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
     <option value="Price">Price</option>
     <option value="3P">3P</option>
     <option value="Freight Collect">Freight Collect</option>
     <option value="Change in Relationships">Change in Relationships</option>
</select>
```

In order for an event to trigger you need to add a listener to your drop down. In jQuery this is very easy to subscribe to the on change event.

And your jQuery would look like this:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#Reason').change(function () {
               alert('select value has changed to ' + $('#Reason').val());

               UpdateRecords();
          });
     });
</script>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code

```
$('#Reason').change(function () {

$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text();
```

or

```
$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").val();

});
```

Comment: Did you tried like this <code>$('#Reason').change(function () { $("#Reason option:selected").text(); });</code> @veena

Comment: @selva do you know what a `<code>` block is? I think you mean a `<script>` tag.