# How to click ActionLink automatically when the dropdown is changes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have one dropdown and one actionlink.
where this actionlink will be clicked automatically when the dropdown changes. How to do that?. below is my code, thanks.

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PaymentCode, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.JenisPembayarans, new { @class = "form-control" })
   @Html.ActionLink(
                       "Detail",
                       "GetInsuranceCompany","ParamBlacklistPembayaran",
                       new { id = Model.PaymentCode }, new { @class = "ddlSubmit"})
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult GetInsuranceCompany( ParamBlacklistPembayaranViewModel model,string id)
{ 
  LoadThirdPartyDDL(string.Empty, string.Empty, id);
  return View("Create", model);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PaymentCode, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.JenisPembayarans, new { @class = "form-control",@id="ddl" })


@Html.ActionLink("Detail",
                       "GetInsuranceCompany","ParamBlacklistPembayaran",
                       new { id = "PaymentCodeVal" }, new { @id="anchorclick",@class = "ddlSubmit"})
```

You should call click event on drop down change like this:

```
 <script>
        document.getElementById('ddl').onchange = function () {
         var  path =  document.getElementById('anchorclick').href;
                      path = path.replace("PaymentCodeVal", document.getElementById('ddl').value);
                      document.getElementById("anchorclick").href=path; 
                      document.getElementById('anchorclick').click();
    };
 </script>
```

**@NOTE :** You want get updated PaymentCode. you have to inject url to pass PaymentCode on change event.

Comment: it's not working. I make a breakpoint in the controller if actionlink is clicked. but nothing happened.

Comment: @chaeusangchen read answer carefully. you need to bind ID parameter before calling click event.

Comment: I have already posted an ActionMethod in the code above. @Mannan Bahelim

Comment: Are you able to hit breakpoint when you directly click on actionlink ?

Comment: it was successful. I missed a word, I'm sorry for that. but I want to ask one more thing. Why parameter `string id` in `ActionResult GetInsuranceCompany` is always null. 
I take the parameter id from that action link where `id = Model.PaymentCode`

Comment: you need to bind ID parameter before calling click event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193625/discussion-between-mannan-bahelim-and-chaeusang-chen).

Answer (score 1):

Assign onchange event in new {} section where you can raise the event of the particular action link by using their id.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PaymentCode, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.JenisPembayarans, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "MyId", onchange = "MyFunction()" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFunction() {
        //alert('Changed');
        document.getElementsByClassName("ddlSubmit").click();
        $('#YourLabelId').val('ReplaceWithThisValue');
    }
</script>
```

References:
[Handling onchange event in HTML.DropDownList Razor MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973037/handling-onchange-event-in-html-dropdownlist-razor-mvc)

Comment: it's not working. I make a breakpoint in the controller if actionlink is clicked. but nothing happened